# Trigger html form submit as if you clicked on button (but without a button)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

If you have a `<form>` and a `<button type='submit'>` and you click on the submit button, it will do the default form validation, such as checking whether an `<input>` is required or not. It would normally say `Please fill out this field.`

However, if I programmatically submit the form through `$("form").submit()` for example, it would submit it without performing any checks.

Is there a simpler way to perform the default form validations using native JavaScript? There seems to be only `checkValidity()` on the `form` element which return `true` or `false`. And if I call the same native function on the `input` itself, it doesn't really do anything.

Here is a demo code of what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/totszwai/yb7arnda/

Answer (score 1):

For those still struggling:

You can use the `Constraint validation API` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation

```html
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <input type="text" required placeholder="name">
    <input type="text" required placeholder="email">
  </form>
  <button id="save">Submit</button>
</div>
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    console.log("submit ...");
  } else {
    form.reportValidity();
  }
});
```

Check out and play here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-t1vhdn?file=index.js

I hope it helps or gives you ideas. :)

Comment: LOL 5 years later. XD But yeah, I guess hooking up on an event listener on the click would work.

Comment: :D LOL - yeah - I'm a turtle. Anyway, I used the button and a `click` event, but the code could be used in literally any event - what you need would be the form reference so you can `check` and `report` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the answer you are looking for :

JavaScript :

```
document
.getElementById('button')
.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
     document.getElementById('myForm').validate();
});
```

HTML :

```
<form  id="myForm" >
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"  required><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" required><br>
<button id="button">Trigger Form Submit</button>
</form>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/2ahLcd4d/2/

Comment: OP did not ask for jQuery.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 
Changed to JavaScript from jQuery.

Comment: What if i don't have a button in my form? (which is the reason I ask the question) Are you saying that we can't trigger the behavior performed by the button separately?

Comment: @codenamezero whenever you want to submit the form, just execute this  document.getElementById('#myForm').validate();

Comment: Yeah, but I always get `TypeError: $(…).validate is not a function`. I've already search and tried a couple of potential solutions before I ask the question on stackoverflow. It seems that native function only has `checkValidity` from the `form` element and nothing else. And I think `validate` is a jQuery plugin.

Comment: @codenamezero my demo is working fine. Can you post your code?

Comment: @codenamezero the following code works fine as a standalone :

`'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form  id="myForm" action="http://www.w3schools.com/" method="GET">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"  required><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" required><br>
<button id="button">Trigger Form Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
document
.getElementById('button')
.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
     document.getElementById('#myForm').validate();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: @Vikash If you open developer tool in your demo, you will get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of null`. I believe your code is "working" due to some other mysterious way... perhaps because your button was inside the `form`? If you try to simply trigger the validation through debugger console, it will give you exactly what I said before. Pull your button and put it outside the form, and you will see that it doesn't work. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80826/discussion-between-codenamezero-and-vikash).